# .NoClassDefFoundError while working with AndroidSDK jar file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I was trying to call one of the method in Android library of  uiautomatorviewer located at `C:\Users\krrishna\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\uiautomatorviewer.jar`. I tried this library by adding it from IntelliJ -> Project Right Click -> open module settings -> jars directories -> finish

The device object here is the IDevice returned from the library and i get the correct number of devices when i called `AndroidDebugBridge.getDevices()`.

```
 device.getHierarchyViewer().getFocusedWindowName();

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Device
at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.setupViewServer(HierarchyViewer.java:47)
at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.<init>(HierarchyViewer.java:43)
at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.getHierarchyViewer(AdbChimpDevice.java:95)
at com.myandroidcode.android.jframes.JwtFrame$22.mouseReleased(MainFrame.java:621)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2025)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out . its looking for a library at below file called DeviceBridge and it was not able to refer that from other .jar files i have which has DeviceBridge.java class in it. Now i need to see how i can make it refer my other .jar file.

```
com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.setupViewServer(HierarchyViewer.java:47)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. We all figured that a specific jar is missing but what it is ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your library that you're using needs some other libraries itself for example if you download libraries from maven there's a section called compile dependencies that shows the libraries that are required to uset the following library as shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ois8.png)

Comment: In my case how do i know  what libraries i am missing ? I know there are lot of Android SDK libraries but i want to add others only when they are required.

Comment: What library are u using exactly?